# executing svn diff from a nant task

Tags: svn, nant

I am running a nant task to package all the source files into a zip and in the same task, I want to run a svn diff command on one particular folder to notify changes made within that source.
The command that I want to execute, in its simplest form, from the command prompt is :

```
svn diff $Special_Folder$ > Changes_In_$Special_Folder$.patch
```

I have the following xml in a nant target

```
<svn command="diff"
             destination="..\build\Database\Scripts"    
             uri ="http://SVN-server/PATH/To/Src">       
</svn>
```

However, I am getting an error from svn that says
[image: error from svn]. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out a way to get this done. The solution does not involve the nant  task . I was able to get it done through the  task.

```
<target name="takeDiff" >
    <echo message="Taking svn diff of Database scripts...  "/>
     <exec program="svn.exe" 
                commandline="diff Database/Scripts" 
                output="${build.dir}/script_Diff.patch" 
                failonerror="true"/> 
    <echo message="Diff is in ${build.dir}\script_Diff.patch...  "/>
</target>
```